# is there a way to manually install laravelcollective? laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, shared-hosting, laravelcollective

I have installed Laravel on shared hosting using softoculous. Now I am facing an issue. I have followed [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32666164/laravel-5-installing-form-and-html-classes-without-composer) which did not work for me. How can I manually install `laravelcollective` package. I also don't have `SSH` enabled. Therefore, I can't use composer. Everything except package is working fine. I also ran artisan commands using

```
\Artisan::call()
```

but sadly nothing has worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I see only one solution you should upload your vendor folder from your local computer to your server. Although its not a recommended way its probably your only option